# como insertar datos desde un combobox a mysql con php

Tags: php, insert, combobox

buenos dias mi duda es como insertar datos desde un combobox a otra base de datos llamda reporte, me carga los datos de una base llamada maquinas, espero que me puedan ayudar
este es el index2.php

```
   <div class="contact-form">
    <form method="post" action="insertar.php">
    <fieldset>
      <?php
    // Verificamos la conexi�n con el servidor y la base de datos
      $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'academ');
    ?>
        <select>
          <option value="0">Seleccione:</option>
          <?php
    // Realizamos la consulta para extraer los datos
              $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM maquinas ");
              while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    // En esta secci�n estamos llenando el select con datos extraidos de una base de datos.
                echo '<option value="'.$valores[idmaquina].'" name="idmaquina">'.$valores[idmaquina].'</option>';
              }
              while ($valores1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
            ?>
        </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

si me carga las id de todas las maquinas en el combobox, el problema es que no puedo insertarlos en otra base de datos llamada reporte
este es el insertar.php

```
<?php
 require 'conectar.php';
 $idmaquina=$_POST['idmaquina'];
 $tipomaquina=$_POST['tipomaquina'];
 $area=$_POST['area'];
 //aqui es donde se insertan los datos
mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO reporte VALUES ('$idmaquina','$tipomaquina','$area','')");
$query = mysqli_query($conectar, $insertar);
if($query){
   echo "<script> alert('se inserto correctamente');
    location.href = 'index2.php';
   </script>";
}else{
    echo "<script> alert('no se inserto correctamente');
    location.href = 'index2.php';
    </script>";
}
?>
```

gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a stack overflow en español, te invito a terminar [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y puedas obtener tu primer medalla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tienes que poner el **name** a tu `<select>` y no a `<option>`.